# Check if property in each item of array is not null

Tags: javascript, typescript

Given the following object, how can I tell if all employees have a non null value for the SSN property?

```
Employees:
{ id: 0, name: "John", SSN: "1234" }
{ id: 1, name: "Mark", SSN: "1876" }
{ id: 2, name: "Sue", SSN: "98826" }
```

Comment: You can compare `Employees[i].SSN === null` for each employee. The corresponding array methods are [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: The data structure of `Employees` is ambiguous and not valid, as far as I can tell. Is it an array? Or an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `0` is not a valid SSN, you can use `Number(Employees[i].SSN) > 0` to make that determination:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBAogWwA4BsQE8CmmIwLwwDaAsAFAwwDeMAlgCYBcMADADQxgCGCmTARAEE+7AMoiAcvwCMAJgDMAFj4UKAX3YB6DTCgAnAK6YyFavSZT2XHvwBCwmGMkw+UgBwB2AGzKV6mFp0DI3IqWkYYGUtuXmcAYXtHfh8VX01tADNOFAhgkzCmOSjrZwARBIkmMH0UFBS1NJhM7NzQsxgFIpi+OHKnfTA6THSaMEw6GD8AppzjVvCAVk7+ADFkuvXU-wysmZDTcM8l5wBxXv4ATldXGW9NgL1DMgBdAG4yMnT+4CgacBgAC04EEcMAAPAAVGCYAAeUEwA1wlEcAH4mNBdCMAOYwAA+HGqtTx-UGw1GdFUAD4ABQANyyhiY4IAlEw6ShDLRcJCAGRURIwdFY1RUWa6TBQfS6MAwcT6BAAI0wulp9MwADpHEyYBSWG9SKp3qR0iBdDAqaBILBMMg0FhMDAQOl4DaMNgIFrKLMLRAQCh1WhMVTrahXeqrJh2IDgRIgy67UymXrVEA)

```ts
const Employees = [
  { id: 0, name: "A", SSN: "1234"    }, // true
  { id: 1, name: "B", SSN: "1876"    }, // true
  { id: 2, name: "C", SSN: ""        }, // false
  { id: 3, name: "D", SSN: null      }, // false
  { id: 4, name: "E", SSN: undefined }, // false
  { id: 5, name: "F"                 }, // false
  { id: 6, name: "G", SSN: "98826"   }, // true
];

function hasSSN <T extends {SSN?: string | null | undefined}>(value: T): value is T & {SSN: string} {
  return Number(value.SSN) > 0;
}

for (const employee of Employees) {
  console.log(employee.name, hasSSN(employee));
}
```

Demo:

```js
const Employees = [
    { id: 0, name: "A", SSN: "1234" },
    { id: 1, name: "B", SSN: "1876" },
    { id: 2, name: "C", SSN: "" },
    { id: 3, name: "D", SSN: null },
    { id: 4, name: "E", SSN: undefined },
    { id: 5, name: "F" },
    { id: 6, name: "G", SSN: "98826" }, // true
];
function hasSSN(value) {
    return Number(value.SSN) > 0;
}
for (const employee of Employees) {
    console.log(employee.name, hasSSN(employee));
}
```